# datetime error while transferring from mysql to postgres using mysql2pgsql

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, postgresql-9.3, mysql-5.6

While transferring data from MySQL to Postgres using mysql2pgsql I am getting the following error

> `Exception: unknown datetime(6)`

I am using ubuntu 14.04, Mysql5.6 and Postgres9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of mysql2pgsql are you using?
Does your version include the fix for [this](https://github.com/philipsoutham/py-mysql2pgsql/issues/83) issue?
Is the traceback (found in logs) similar?